# Dimension of a vector space $W=\{f \in V; f \circ \pi = f\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $N=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $\pi$ a permutation $\pi: N \rightarrow N$.$$\pi=(14)(235)(67)$$ Let $V$ be the vector space of all functions $N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $W$ be the following set, $$W=\{f \in V; f \circ \pi = f\}$$ **What is the dimension of $W$?**

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? This is just a problem statement, which is generally not received well.

Comment: Also, how can $\pi$ permute $7$ when $7\notin N$?

Comment: Please add at least a modicum of context to tell Readers where your interest or difficulty in this problem lies.  Are you able to make any progress (such as an upper or lower bound on the dimension)?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
 Let $f \in W$, then $f(\pi(1))=f(1) \implies f(4)=f(1)$. Likewise $f(2)=f(3)=f(5)$ and $f(6)=f(7)$. So there is only so much freedom to choose the values for $f$.......???

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$f(1)=f(4)$$
$$f(2)=f(3)=f(5)$$
$$f(6)=f(7)$$
The subspace satisfying these equations has dimension $3$.